# Accessing Appended item with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to append some content into the body of an html page with the Beautiful Soup python library.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup("<html><head></head><body></body></html>", "html.parser")
>>> body = BeautifulSoup("<ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol>", "html.parser")
>>> print doc.html.body.ol
None
>>> doc.html.body.append(body)
>>> print doc.html.body.ol
None
```

After appending, I still am seeing the ol tag as empty.

```
>>> body.ol
<ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol>
>>> doc.html.body
<body><ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol></body>
>>>
```

However. you can see that the content appears to be there if I print the entire body tag. I feel like I do not quite understand the append operation.

Edit:

I do not know why, but it appears that I can append tags but not the root.  For instance, `doc.html.body.append(body.ol)` works as I would expect it to.  I can also do `for tag in body.children: doc.html.body.append(tag)`.

My question is why does the root not append?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append the `body.ol` and not `body`. In other words, append a `Tag` instance and not a `BeautifulSoup` instance:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup("<html><head></head><body></body></html>", "html.parser")
>>> body = BeautifulSoup("<ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol>", "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> doc.html.body.append(body.ol)
>>> 
>>> print(doc.html.body.ol)
<ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol>
```

Or, if you don't know what tag is gonna be the parent, use `body.find()`.

You can also switch the parser to `html5lib` (requires `html5lib` [to be installed](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> doc = BeautifulSoup("<html><head></head><body></body></html>", "html5lib")
>>> body = BeautifulSoup("<ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol>", "html5lib")
>>> 
>>> doc.html.body.append(body)
>>> print(doc.html.body.ol)
<ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol>
```

Comment: I still do not understand the intended behavior of append, because it seems like the parser should not change this behavior as it should already be "parsed" at this point.
It looks like a work around for this would be:

<code>for tag in body.children: doc.html.body.append(tag)</code>

For some reason the root will not append with the html.parser

Comment: @rileymat sorry for last comment, it is the other way around, but that's not exactly relevant - removed the comment. Updated the answer with how to make it work without changing the parser.

Comment: Thanks, in this contrived example I know that it is an ol tag underneath, but in my actual app I do not know what it will be.  Iterating through children seems to work.  Change it to iterate and I will accept the answer, as it may help someone.  It is an odd difference for the parsers though.

Comment: @rileymat yeah, you can use `body.find()` to get the very parent element..thanks, it's not completely clear what is happening, I agree.